# Xamarin Forms ListView not updating without navigating to new page

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I'm creating my first app using Xamarin Forms. I initially had some trouble getting my views to update with my bindings but I received some great help from the people on here and was able to grasp the concept. Now I'm trying to learn how to implement ListViews into my app. I'm running into the exact same problem as before, my Listview isn't updating when I click the button to advance a game day. The day value in my stacklayout on the same page updates fine and my bindings and everything are written the same way as the other pages and data I have that update but still nothing happens to the ListView. Also I am using an observable collection which I know is supposed to update the view when an item is changed, added or deleted. The data does however update if I open my menu and navigate to a new instance of the page so I know the button and everything else is working fine it's just the view that isn't updating. I'm sure it is probably something silly that I'm not seeing, as it was with my other issues but any help would be great. I've been stuck starring at the problem for sometime now and have yet to find solution on the internet. Thanks in advance!

Here is my DrugInventoryPage.xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KingPinMobile.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="KingPinMobile.Views.DrugInventoryPage"
             Title="Inventory">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:PlayerInventoryViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="+24hrs" Command="{Binding PIVMOn1Turn}"   />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="20">
                <Label Text="Money:" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                <Label x:Name="lblPlayerMoney"  Text="{Binding Money, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Padding="0">
                <BoxView HeightRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Color="Gray" />
            </StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="lvPlayerDrugs" ItemsSource="{Binding PlayerDrugs}">
                <ListView.Header>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Text="Drug" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="LightGray"/>
                        <Label Text="Quantity" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="LightGray"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ListView.Header>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Quantity}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                            </Grid>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is the DrugInventoryPage.xaml.cs:

```cs
using KingPinMobile.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace KingPinMobile.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class DrugInventoryPage : ContentPage
    {
        public DrugInventoryPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the PlayerInventoryViewModel.cs:

```cs
using Engine;
using KingPinMobile.Views;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace KingPinMobile.ViewModels
{
    public class PlayerInventoryViewModel : HomePageViewModel
    {
        public PlayerInventoryModel model = new PlayerInventoryModel();

        public ObservableCollection<DrugInventoryItem> Player1Drugs = new ObservableCollection<DrugInventoryItem>();


        public PlayerInventoryViewModel()
        {
            PIVMOn1Turn = new Command(execute: PIVMOn1Turns);
            Player1Drugs = model.PlayerDrugs;
        }

        public ICommand PIVMOn1Turn { get; private set; }
        public ObservableCollection<DrugInventoryItem> PlayerDrugs
        {
            get { return Player1Drugs; }

            set { Player1Drugs = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public void PIVMOn1Turns()
        {
            _model.On1Turn();

            _model.refreshModel();

            model.refreshPlayerInventoryModel();

            CurrentDay = Math.Floor(ProgressionDirectory.CurrentGameDay.DayNumber).ToString();

            Money = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(World._player.PlayerMoney)).ToString();

            PlayerDrugs = World._player.DrugInventory;

            Player1Drugs = World._player.DrugInventory;


        }
    }
}
```

Here is the HomePageViewModel.cs the previous ViewModel inherits from:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Engine;
using Hangfire.Annotations;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace KingPinMobile
{

    public class HomePageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public static HomeModel _model = new HomeModel();

        public Player _player = _model.Player1;

        public string Day = _model.DayText;

        public string MoneyValue = _model.MoneyText;

        public string CurrentLocation = _model.Player1.CurrentLocation.Name;

        public HomePageViewModel()
        {
            OnTurn = new Command(execute: On1Turn);
        }

        public ICommand OnTurn { get; private set; }
        public string CurrentDay
        {

            get { return Day; }

            set { Day = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }

        }


        public string Money
        {

            get { return MoneyValue; }

            set { MoneyValue = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public string PlayerLocation
        {

            get { return CurrentLocation; }

            set { CurrentLocation = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public void On1Turn()
        {
            _model.On1Turn();

            _model.refreshModel();

            CurrentDay = Math.Floor(ProgressionDirectory.CurrentGameDay.DayNumber).ToString();

            Money = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(World._player.PlayerMoney)).ToString();                      

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }        
    }    
}
```

Here is the PlayerInventoryModel.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Engine
{
    public class PlayerInventoryModel : HomeModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<DrugInventoryItem> PlayerDrugs = World._player.DrugInventory;

        public void refreshPlayerInventoryModel()
        {
            PlayerDrugs = World._player.DrugInventory;
            refreshModel();
        }        
    }
}
```

Finally the HomeModel.cs that the previous Model inherits from:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Engine;

namespace Engine
{
    public class HomeModel
    {
        public string DayText = Math.Floor(ProgressionDirectory.CurrentGameDay.DayNumber).ToString();
        //public decimal Money = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(World._player.PlayerMoney)).;
        public string MoneyText = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(World._player.PlayerMoney)).ToString();
        public Day CurrentDay = ProgressionDirectory.CurrentGameDay;
        public Player Player1 = World._player;
        public string TrueDay = ProgressionDirectory.CurrentGameDay.DayNumber.ToString();

        public void On1Turn()
        {
            Day CurrentGameDay = ProgressionDirectory.CurrentGameDay;
            Advance1DAY.Advance1DAYS(CurrentGameDay);
            decimal TurnsPassed = 1;
            Sell.DrugsOnTurn(TurnsPassed);
            ActionDirectory.OnTurn(TurnsPassed);
        }

        public void refreshModel()
        {
            DayText = Math.Floor(ProgressionDirectory.CurrentGameDay.DayNumber).ToString();
            MoneyText = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(World._player.PlayerMoney)).ToString();
            CurrentDay = ProgressionDirectory.CurrentGameDay;
            Player1 = World._player;
            TrueDay = ProgressionDirectory.CurrentGameDay.DayNumber.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you shared most of your code, can you put it in a private repo that we can run and build to troubleshoot?

Comment: I read fast your code, but when and where do you change the PlayerDrugs else than in the PlayerInventoryViewModel.cs ?

Is it this line you expect to update your view ?
`PlayerDrugs = World._player.DrugInventory;`

Comment: @Umar3x Yes that is the line I intended to update PlayerDrugs. The actual value is updated in the World.cs class during during ```Sell.DrugsOnTurn(TurnsPassed)``` in the On1Turn method that is called when the button click triggers PIVMOn1Turn. Also the refresh model methods refresh the models used in the View Models. I'm not sure why the line ```PlayerDrugs = World._player.DrugInventory;``` wouldn't work, if you look in the HomePageViewModel.cs I update Money in the same way in On1Turn method with ```Money = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(World._player.PlayerMoney)).ToString();```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get why you got this implementation instead of having backing fields for your properties and raise property changed when you want another property to be aware of the changes, but anyway, you return or set a `Player1Drugs` collection. Btw, why do you set `Player1Drugs` here in the setter ?

```
   public ObservableCollection<DrugInventoryItem> PlayerDrugs
    {
        get { return Player1Drugs; }

        set { Player1Drugs = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

However, as I told you, maybe you should do some refactoring on your properties, thus your `PlayerDrugs` can be aware of any changes on `Player1Drugs`.

```
 public ObservableCollection<DrugInventoryItem> PlayerDrugs => Players1Drugs;



 private ObservableCollection<DrugInventoryItem> _player1Drugs;
 public ObservableCollection<DrugInventoryItem> Player1Drugs
    {
        get { return _player1Drugs; }

        set {
              if(_player1Drugs == value) return;
              _player1Drugs = value; 
              OnPropertyChanged();
              OnPropertyChanged("PlayerDrugs") 
           }
    }
```

Or, doing two properties with backing fields (like the one just above for  `Player1Drugs`), and re-arrange your code logic.

**EDIT** : Ran your sample and got it working. If you want to trigger the property changes, you should create a new `ObservableCollection` in your `PIVMon1Turns()` :

```
Player1Drugs = new ObservableCollection<DrugInventoryItem>(World.Player1.DrugInventory);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input! Unfortunately I tried switching those two lines and that didn't work so I tried to refactor my code in the manner you suggested and it didn't work either. I don't know why I'm having such a hard time getting this to work.

Comment: Hmm. As stated in the comment, could you reproduce it in a minimalistic project thus I can run & test it ?

Comment: I'll get to work on that in my spare time later this evening.

Comment: Here is the link for the repository. It is just the Page in question with a menu to re instance the page for testing. The Money updates and the Drug quantity updates upon re instancing the page, and all the code is the same I just stripped it of the unnecessary values from the home page. Don't mind all the commented out code in the PlayerInventoryViewModel.cs, it's the original code I had before refactoring as you suggested.

Comment: @jordan1300,I download your sample, but I can not run your project at my side, it have some errors.According to my understanding, you want to update ListView Item data by click Toolbar? if yes, you should choose ListView Item firstly, then pass the value like Id to command, so it can find this record by Id in Observablecollection, update data.

Comment: @Umar3x This worked great thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Invoke Property as Send property Name

```
 OnPropertyChanged("PlayerLocation");
```